# Disable button using php, Not working

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli

Can anyone suggest something I am using osclass opensource.
I don't know why conditions not working.

```
<button type="button" class="button-ii" <?php if(osc_item_formated_price()=="Only Information Available" || $email == "OFF")  {?> disabled="true" <?php } ?><?php>data-toggle="modal"disabled data-target="#myModal">Enquiry</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, What have you tried to achieve your wanted results? What has your research concerning your problem shown? Can you provide code of your tries? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) wherever required. Also please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you doing a wrong practice with PHP code you have an Extra `<?php`  within button try this code may this help you either.

```
<button type="button" class="button-ii" 
<?php if(osc_item_formated_price()=="Only Information Available" || $email == "OFF")  
{?> disabled="true" <?php } ?> >data-toggle="modal"disabled data-target="#myModal">Enquiry</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it with different approach,

```
<?php if(osc_item_formated_price()=="Only Information Available" || $email == "OFF") { ?>
    <button type="button" class="button-ii" disabled>Enquiry</button>
<?php } else { ?>
    <button type="button" class="button-ii" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Enquiry</button>
<?php } ?>
```

OR

```
<?php if(osc_item_formated_price()=="Only Information Available" || $email == "OFF") { 
    echo '<button type="button" class="button-ii" disabled>Enquiry</button>';
} else {
    echo '<button type="button" class="button-ii" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Enquiry</button>';
}
```

**EDIT:**
I also want to point out that you need to change `disable=true` to **`disabled`**.

And this line `data-toggle="modal"disabled` does not make sense, remove `disabled` after `data-toggle="modal"`.

You also have an extra `php` opening tag here `<?php>data-toggle="modal"disabled` without a closing. You should remove that refer to the code above.